# How can you parse this line into name=value pairs in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with the following format where each name=value pair is separated by a space.  Records are separated by a newline.

```
value1=1 value2="This is a string" value3=40 value4="Yes"
```

What is the easiest way in Perl to parse the above string into it's name=value pair? I have tried a few approachs but they all fail with value2 having some spaces in the associated value.

There is plenty of things covering CSV parsing in Perl, but this seems to be slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'value1=1 value2="This is a string" value3=40 value4="Yes"';

my %pairs = $s =~ / (\S+) \s* = \s* ( [^\s"]+ | "[^"]*" ) /gx;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%pairs;
```

**output**

```
{
  value1 => 1,
  value2 => "\"This is a string\"",
  value3 => 40,
  value4 => "\"Yes\"",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regex to do this and kind of validate data, you can try this one that should account for escaping :

```
\w+=(?:'.*?(?<!\\)'|".*?(?<!\\)"|\w+)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wK0eD2

*Explanation*

```
\w+=             # [0-9_a-zA-Z]+=
(?:              # non-capturing group
    '.*?         # single quote and everything until...
    (?<!\\)'     # first single quote not preceded by antislash
|                # OR
    ".*?         # double quote and everything until...
    (?<!\\)"     # first double quote not preceded by antislash
|                # OR
    \w+          # string of alphanum characters
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
 ([^\s=]++)=(?|"((?>[^"]++|"")*)"|(\S+))
```

With the branch reset feature `(?|...|...)` the value is always in group 2.